# Moving files to matching folders on linux command line

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash, terminal

I would like to copy or move files in to matching folders. 
these are my filenames:

```
1-filename-aa.txt
2-filename-aa.txt
3-filename-aa.txt
1-filename-bb.txt
2-filename-bb.txt
3-filename-bb.txt
```

these are my folder names:

```
aa_fa
bb_fb
```

I tried just static examples with "cp" command but I have 40 folders like this:

```
cp *aa.* aa_*/
cp *bb.* bb_*/
```

I need a loop maybe 1 line code to copy or move these files to matching folders.

Comment: If you have 40, please say how you name the files and folders beyond `z`.

Comment: Crossposting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57415329/3776858

Comment: Is there any pattern for last two chars of directory names ?

Comment: @Yasen nope it's just random

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner:

```sh
for filename in *.txt; do cp $filename $(echo $filename | grep -Po '..(?=\.txt)'); done
```